# How to check ga dimensions(Google Analytics)?

Tags: google-analytics

As per my code I am setting the 'dimension1' field. 
Defined fields: email(contains user email)

```
    ga('set', 'dimension1', email);
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

How to see the dimension1 values in GA?

Original requirement: Track id of each user.

Comment: Be very very careful, read the [Terms of Service](https://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html) especially the part about PII: "You will not and will not assist or permit any third party to, pass information to Google that Google could use or recognize as personally identifiable information."

Comment: Heed @Matt's warning, and do NOT collect email into your GA. Pretty much a no-no.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the reporting interface, not programming (hint: use secondary dimensions in your reports or create a custom report. And do not store data that identifies a person).